# Call different subs from different modules

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call the different subs in different modules from my main module.
When I do the `exit sub` at the end, only "brief 1" will be created.
If I don't put the `exit sub` after each call, it will make first "brief1", and goes further and within the loop it will create for each row all of the letters instead of the one it needs.

```vb
Dim r As Long

r = 6
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(r, 1))

With Sheet1

    If Sheet1.Range("C" & r) = "Brief 1" Then
        Rappelbrief_1
         
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C" & r) = "Brief 2" Then
        Rappelbrief_2
                         
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C" & r) = "Brief 3" Then
        Rappelbrief_3
                    
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C" & r) = "Brief BA" Then
        Brief_BA       
         
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C" & r) = "Brief na tel contact" Then
        Brief_opheffen_na_telefonisch_contact

    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C" & r) = "Brief tel. opheffing" Then
        Brief_Tel_Opheffing
                                
    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C" & r) = "Brief 1 + ophefform" Then
        Rappelbrief_1
        Brief_opheffen_na_telefonisch_contact
        'Ophefform_PDF
                                    
    End If
```

Comment: What method are you using to increase the value of `r`?  Your code seems incomplete for what you are trying to accomplish.  It appears you are trying to loop through 6 separate cells, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have `IsEmpty(Cells(r, 1))` without a worksheet reference, which might lead to problems.

Try something like this instead:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim c As Range
    
    Set c = Sheet1.Range("A6")
    
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        Select Case c.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Case "Brief 1": Rappelbrief_1
            Case "Brief 2": Rappelbrief_2
            Case "Brief 3": Rappelbrief_3
            'etc etc
            Case "Brief 1 + ophefform"
                Rappelbrief_1
                Brief_opheffen_na_telefonisch_contact
        End Select
    
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim voor looking into it.
Only problem I have now, is that I'll get a runtime error on one of the subs I'm calling, while, running the code from that particular sub on itself, it doesn't get the runtime error 91.

Comment: There's not much I can offer there -sounds like the error is in another Sub...

Comment: ...without seeing that code and the specific error it's impossible to suggest anything.